# Help on understanding Gardner's original paper for QPSK symbol timing recovery?

Tags: digital-communications, digital-filters, pll, symbol-timing

I am fairly new to DSP and RF receivers in general, and I was recommended to read Gardner's original [paper](https://www.academia.edu/10373883/A_BPSKQPSK_Timing-Error_Detector_for_Sampled_Receivers) for symbol timing error recovery for QPSK signals.

I have a question regarding an equation for early-late gates; in the following picture, why is `L(r-1)` equal to `x^2((r-5/4)*T)`? It seems to me that it should be `x^2((r-3/4)*T)`. Am I missing something?

[image]

Also, intuitively, if the spacing for the Early and Late is 1/4 each, then the spacing between Early and Late should be `2 * 1/4 T = 1/2 T`, not `1 * T`.

Comment: You are right. It should have been 3/4. Otherwise I am missing to understand something obvious. May be a typo.

Comment: I agree looks like a typo. I have more info on how the Gardner TED works at this post that may further help you in your study: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62453/nda-timing-estimation-for-mutli-level-qamrc-pulse/62454#624544